# Context Path Configuration Using Spring 3.1 MVC

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

My question is related to the context path.I have deployed my web application on tomcat also with domain register.Now the thing is i want to hide the context path such as

```
www.ABC.com should be pointed to my application
but 
www.ABC.com/myAPP/ is working write now
```

Though i know it can  be achieve by configuring server.xml of tomcat and also by using redirect rule but the problem is Tomcat server is being used by many other application so context path rule can be implement only for one application for a isolated server. Now i am wondering weather it can be achieve by using any context path configuration of spring MVC or by any other mean.

Any Knowledge would help me a lot.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

if its a war file, just rename war to ROOT.war, and delete the original ROOT directory in webapps. Then copy your new ROOT.war to webapps directory. Then www.abc.com should work fine.